# Positioning below absolutely positioned divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I have two `<div>`s with `absolute` `position`. One is displayed and the other is `display: none` on load. When the link on the visible one is clicked it is moved and the other is displayed.

I have a third `<div>` with link that I would like to display directly below these. Since they’re both `position: absolute` I have not been able to find a way to do this. I have found various solutions, but most of them are workarounds for using absolute position. Since my `<div>`s need to show ontop of each other I unfortunately can’t remove the absolute positioning.

As such I have tried various combinations of `position: absolute` and `position: relative` on the three `<div>`s, but so far nothing has worked.

JSFiddle with my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/dagz9tLw/1/

`<div>` with id `linkbar` is the one that needs to be at the bottom.

The other two `<div>`s don’t have a set height so `margin-top` won’t work. `linkbar` also needs to be just below the `<div>`s and not right at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Is it possible to put all those `<div>`s into another `<div>` and make _that_ one absolutely positioned? Or did I get the question wrong? Or is it somehow possible to group some of those `<div>`s together?

Comment: When the div is moved, should the links be moved down with it or should the div overlap the links?

Comment: @Xufox it can, but then the back div is positioned below the front div aswell when it is made visible.

Comment: @RobertCordes the links should be moved down yes, but not right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experienced that using a `div` acting as a `buffer` is quite useful and easy to implement for this purpose. You just set it above your `div#linkbar` and adjust it's height on load and when the `div#front` get's repositioned:

```js
$("#topBuffer").css("height", $("#front").offset().top + $("#front").height());

$("#showLink").click(function() {
  if (!$("#back").is(":visible")) {
    $("#back").show();

    $("#front").animate({
      'marginLeft': "+=30px"
    });
    $("#front").animate({
      'marginTop': "+=20px"
    });
    $("#topBuffer").animate({
      'height': "+=20px"
    });
  }

  return true;
});
```

```css
.front {
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: white;
}
.back {
  display: none;
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="front" class="front">
  <a id="showLink" href="javascript:void(0);">front</a>
</div>
<div id="back" class="back">
  <a href="">back</a>
</div>
<div id="topBuffer"></div>
<div id="linkbar">
  <a href="">test</a>
  <a href="">test</a>
  <a href="">test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @Vinc Btw: if you want the sliding down of the elements, you can put the `$("#front").animate({
                'marginTop': "+=20px"
            });
            $("#topBuffer").animate({
                'height': "+=20px"
            });` in an anonymous callback function for the sliding right animation

Comment: firebug is currently showing `TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined` im using jQuery 1.11.0 and jQuery UI 1.10.3 yet using that version in jsfiddle works, am I missing something

Comment: Nevermind fixed it was running the `$("#topBuffer").css("height", $("#front").offset().top + $("#front").height());` line before the document was ready. This works perfectly thanks.